# connection result in authentification google is 10

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-oauth

I try coding authentification with google but when I execute application I have alert content 10

this is code login:

```
  login(): Promise<any>{

           return this.googleplus.login({
            'webClientId': 'idApp'
          }).then((x: ILoginResponse) => {
               x.access_token;
          }, (err) => {
              alert(err);
          });

      }
```

how to resolve this error please

Comment: I think that link help you https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243

Comment: also error :( ...

Answer (score 0):

Create **SHA-1** (dev) with

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Keystore password: android

You will get dev SHA-1 that need to be imported to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/

[image]

And, under `webClientId` inside login function goes your app's `Web client ID` from Firebase Console.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public _navCtrl: NavController, 
              public _navParams: NavParams,
              public _googlePlus: GooglePlus) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  loginGoogle(){
    this._googlePlus.login({
      'webClientId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem('userEmail', res.email);
        localStorage.setItem('userName', res.displayName);
        localStorage.setItem('userImage', res.imageUrl);
        this._navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I followed your example but also error and also i followed this tuto but also error : https://www.djamware.com/post/59094a2280aca7414e78a63d/ionic-3-google-plus-authentication-tutorial
:(
I download file google-services.json and in this file i have 2 client ID . I try authentification with 2 client ID but also error :( ... this error blocked my work